# Can't authenticate users in Django app

Tags: python, django, http

I'm trying to make a website using Django, and I have several views that require logins. However, I can't figure out how to authenticate users. I'm extremely new to web development (this is my first project), so please ask follow-up questions if I am not being clear. Here is some code that might provide context:

Excerpt from rushsite/rush/views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

def login_user(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('list')
        else:
            return render(request, "registration/login.html")
    else:
        return render(request, "registration/login.html")
```

My login.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="top">
            <h1 id="title" class="hidden"><span id="logo">Delta Sig<span> Recruitment</span></span></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="login-box animated fadeInUp">
            <div class="box-header">
                <h2>Log In</h2>
            </div>
            <form method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <label for="username">Username</label>
                <br/>
                <input type="text" id="username">
                <br/>
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <br/>
                <input type="password" id="password">
                <br/>
                <button type="submit">Sign In</button>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                {% if request.META.HTTP_REFERER == "http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/" %} Incorrect username or password. {% endif %}
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Excerpt from rushsite/rush/models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator

class Brother(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

When I click submit on my form using credentials that I know are valid, the user = None so it just redirects me right back to the login page. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think it might have to do with the fact that I have a Brother model that is a OneToOneField with users. I'm not quite sure what this means, though.

Comment: Can you debug that the values you think you  are posting are really arriving in the view?

Answer (score 0):

As you're not doing anything strange with your login view, you should use [django's pre-made authentication views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views). This avoids the normal kinds of issues that can sneak in when re-inventing the wheel.

It also includes some extra functionality, such as use of django's forms, and redirection upon successful login based on the `?next=` GET arg.

In this case, you need [`LoginView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView).

I would also recommend looking into [django's built-in forms(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/). If you *did* need to write your own view for this, forms would be good for validation. They can [simplify your template code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/#form-rendering-options), and will show validation errors appropriately.

Using the form that comes automatically with `LoginView`, the `<form>` in your template could be reduced to:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
</form>
```